# when msg.sender is the owner?

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, addresses

how do I know if the msg.sender is the owner (the person that deployed) of the contract or a random address that interacted with the contract?
in this case for example:

```
    address payable owner  =  msg.sender;   

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function close() public onlyOwner { 
    selfdestruct(owner);  
}
```

why isn't the msg.sender reset at each interaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solidity enables constructors which have code executed at contract creation. So you need to instantiate `owner` in the constructor to catch the contract deployer address :

```
address payable owner;
constructor() public {
owner = msg.sender;
}
```

There are also standardized contracts to manage ownership. Exemple of implementation can be found here : https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol.

Comment: yes, I know that but my question was a bit different.
for example how does the contract know that I am not the owner?
msg.sender is the person that interacts with the contract

Comment: `owner` is set at the deployment. So let's say for exemple the `msg.sender` who deploys the contract is the address "0xabc...". Your smart contract then registers `owner=0xabc...`. Next, if someone with the address "0x123..." interacts with the contract and calls the `close` function, the modifier will see that "0x123..." (the `msg.sender`) is different from the owner address ("0xabc...") and the transaction will be rejected.

Comment: oh ok thnkx :))